# Git asks for non-existing path bash: /usr/share/gitolite/gl-auth-command

Tags: git, gitolite

The command git that always worked well started to ask for the non-existing path:

```
$ git pull origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/home/xxxxx/.ssh/xxxxxxxx_rsa': 
bash: /usr/share/gitolite/gl-auth-command: No such file or directory
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The path, indeed, is missing on both server and workstation side and I even cannot understand which side (server or workstation) is responsible for the problem. How to get the git working again?

The passphrase protected key and the authentication itself seems ok as it is possible to use them for ssh login.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that after installing `gitolite3` on the server side and then running `gitolite` as `git` results the error message that `.gitolite.rc` has the wrong content for the old version. After moving this file away, it was possible to fix everything with `gitolite setup`. All content was surely backed up during this migration. Maybe somebody will post a more consistent answer.